# Why is my interval function causing a memory leak in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks

I have a `Node.js` server that is experiencing a memory leak. It uses `socket.io` to emit messages to the connected clients. I have set up a function that sends a message to the clients once per minute. The function is:

```
var message = "smile";
const doEveryMinute = (socket) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        setInterval(() => doEveryMinute(socket), 6000);
        socket.emit('smile', message);   
    }, (60 - date.getSeconds()) * 1000);
}
```

The function is called when a user connects, by the `io.on` function as such:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket){
    doEveryMinute(socket);
});
```

I cannot see why this would cause a memory leak, but it certainly is causing one. I can see on `htop` that the ram slowly but surely fills up until the server crashes displaying a `memory overflow exception` message.

### Question:

Why does this code cause a memory leak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, 6000 is 6 seconds, not 60 seconds.

You never call `clearInterval`, so the timer you create using `setInterval` will hang around forever, being called every 6 seconds. Remember this is `setInterval`, not `setTimeout`, so the timer doesn't stop after it has fired the first time.

In itself that isn't necessarily a problem as the memory usage of a single timer would be negligible.

However, the function called by your timer calls `doEveryMinute`, which will create another timer. It'll grow exponentially as each timer creates another one 6 seconds later.

If you just want to send a message every 60 seconds you don't need the recursion, just a single timer that calls `emit`:

```
var message = "smile";
const doEveryMinute = (socket) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        setInterval(() => socket.emit('smile', message), 60000);
    }, (60 - date.getSeconds()) * 1000);
}
```

Note that this still isn't perfect as it never stops the timer, you'd need to add a suitable call to `clearInterval` when the connection drops. I've also made some dubious assumptions about the reliability of `setInterval` to fire after exactly 60s. I'm wondering whether your original code was trying to deal with the inexactness of the timers? That's fine but you need to stick to `setTimeout` rather than `setInterval` if you want to do that.